# Update array elements by index if they don't contain some key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update multiple elements in an array in a particular document, where I have the indices of the elements that need to be updated, only if some key does not exist.

[MongoDB Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HHChu79c4Cp)

Suppose I have a document:

```
{
    "key": 1,
    "questions": [
      {
        "text": "first",
      },
      {
        "text": "second",
      },
      {
        "text": "third",
        "answered": "balloon",
      },
    ],
},
```

I want to update the 2nd and 3rd items (index 2 and 3) with a new "answered" field, but only update the ones which doesn't have the "answered" field already.
Here is the query I managed so far:

```
db.collection.update({
  "key": 1,
},
{
  $set: {
    "questions.1.answered": "second answer",
    "questions.2.answered": "third answer",
  }
}
)
```

This is updating both the 2nd and 3rd indices, and setting "answered" to both of them. But I want to skip the "3rd" one as it already had "answered" key.
How can I achieve this exclusion?
Maybe something in the lines of ArrayFilters?

Expected output:

```
{
    "key": 1,
    "questions": [
      {
        "text": "first",
      },
      {
        "text": "second",
        "answered": "second answer", //Added field
      },
      {
        "text": "third",
        "answered": "balloon", //Should not update as it already had "answered"
      },
    ],
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You want optional update, so i used a pipeline update.
Maybe you can do it with update operators only, but the bellow works ok also.

Query

- on "data" put the answers array and the corresponding indexes
- map on indexes of questions `(0 1 2 ...)`
- check if the index is in those that need to be changed
- if they dont have answer get an answer

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251b323f7e3c64c6511e174)

```js
update({"key" : 1},
[{"$set": 
    {"data": {"answers": ["index1-a", "index2-a"], "indexes": [1, 2]}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"questions": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": {"$range": [0, {"$size": "$questions"}]},
          "in": 
          {"$let": 
            {"vars": {"question": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$questions", "$$this"]}},
              "in": 
              {"$cond": 
                [{"$and": 
                    [{"$in": ["$$this", "$data.indexes"]},
                      {"$eq": [{"$type": "$$question.answered"}, "missing"]}]},
                  {"$mergeObjects": 
                    ["$$question",
                      {"answered": 
                        {"$arrayElemAt": 
                          ["$data.answers",
                            {"$indexOfArray": ["$data.indexes", "$$this"]}]}}]},
                  {"$arrayElemAt": ["$questions", "$$this"]}]}}}}}}},
  {"$unset": ["data"]}])
```